# Retrieve old value with validation for dynamic form in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have an issue.

I have dynamic form as per user wants.

Everything is going good except i cannot retrieve old values when validation occurs. What i want is validation message with old input values. The problem is due to dynamic form .

Here is my code :

```
    <div class="col-sm-5">

          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="key_name[]"

                                       placeholder="Size" value="{{ old('key_name[]') }}">

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-5">

         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="key_value[]"

                                       placeholder="Price" value="{{ old('key_value[]') }}">
    </div>


     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-field"><i

                                        class="ion-trash-a"></i> Delete

     </button>
       @if ($errors->has('key_name[]'))
               <div class="error-add-size-message">
                  <span class="help-block">
                   <strong> * {{ $errors->first('key_name[]') }}</strong>
                 </span>
               </div>
        @endif
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you send ->withinput() parameter from controller?

Comment: I have problem that i donot know how many form user will choose as it is dynamic so i cannot index array like key_name.0 so how to do indexing so that old values can be retreived correspondingly .

Comment: If i do key_name.0 then old values for key_name.0 can be obtained but as it is dynamic i want to retrieve other form also such as key_name.1 key_name.2 so on. Any ideaas how to get this from dynamic form. Kevin Antala

Answer (score 0):

You can count form inputs in your controller and flash this count in the session.

```
$count = count($request->input("key_name"));
session()->flash("form_count",$count);
```

Comment: i got no feedback for my answer , i think this should work .@msbomrel
try it and tell me :)